Unable to import GCP URL map configuration: 'defaultCustomErrorResponsePolicy' error in gcloud CLI"
I am trying to import a URL map configuration into GCP using the following command:
gcloud compute url-maps import loadbalancer-name --source loadbalancer-name.yaml

I am getting the following error:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.url-maps.import) Additional properties are not allowed ('defaultCustomErrorResponsePolicy' was unexpected)

Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema:
    {'$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#',
     'additionalProperties': False,
     'description': 'A gcloud export/import command YAML validation '
                    'schema.',

The loadbalancer-name.yaml file includes the property defaultCustomErrorResponsePolicy, which is causing the issue. Is this property deprecated or unsupported? How can I resolve this and successfully import the configuration?
According to Google's official documentation, the defaultCustomErrorResponsePolicy is still referenced as a valid property for handling 404 redirects to a backend service or bucket. The configuration example provided uses this property for redirecting 404 errors.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!
My loadbalancer-name.yaml
creationTimestamp: '2024-11-14T22:58:53.712-08:00'
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/bucket-name
defaultCustomErrorResponsePolicy:
  errorResponseRules:
    - matchResponseCodes:
      - 4xx
      path: '/not-found.html'
  errorService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/bucket-name
fingerprint: x57Iq75VdBI=
id: 1151498730841538498
kind: compute#urlMap
name: loadbalancer-name
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/urlMaps/loadbalancer-name



I attempted to use the defaultCustomErrorResponsePolicy property in my url-maps configuration YAML to set up a 404 error redirect to a backend bucket, as shown in Google's official documentation. I expected the configuration to import successfully and handle 404 errors by redirecting requests to the specified error page in the backend bucket. I even tried redirecting requests to backend services and custom API URL.
